# booting in text mode by using boot parameter in kali linux

Tags: systemd, boot, kali-linux, tty, boot-loader

I'm following [the recommendation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/542575/100397) from an earlier question, which tells me,

> Use boot parameter `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` to boot in text mode.

How do I do this? I can't access GUI so I need to get to text mode.

Answer (score 1):

When you power on or reset a x86-based Linux system, you'll usually first see the system manufacturer's logo, and/or some other messages from the system firmware. After that, the Linux bootloader will display its boot menu or logo. (It might be the logo of the Linux distribution in question.)

On a x86-based Linux system, this is usually GRUB, but other bootloaders like SYSLINUX and rEFInd do exist. Kali Linux appears to be using GRUB.

The boot process may go forward automatically at this point after a short delay. But usually the automatic boot can be stopped by pressing any key. If a full-screen logo was originally displayed, it will usually be replaced or overlaid with a boot menu at this point.

With GRUB, make sure you have the boot menu option you wish to use selected, and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key to edit the boot entry. These edits will be non-persistent, as GRUB has only read-only filesystem access at this point.

Find the line that starts with the word `linux` and includes the pathname to a file whose name normally includes the word `vmlinuz`. After the filename, the boot options (usually there is at least some of them) are listed. Go to the end of the line, and type in a space and `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`. Note that the keyboard will probably use an US English default layout, which may be different from what is actually printed on the keyboard.

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot with your modified boot options, as instructed towards the bottom of the display.

Here is an example with a picture, although it uses somewhat different boot options:

https://kali.training/topic/exercise-2-3-editing-boot-parameters/

Click on "Show Answer" to see the picture.